Invalid context for 'super' invocation
I have a separate widget which I call dashboard, then when I want to do initstate an error like this appears.
Invalid context for 'super' invocation.
this is an example of some of my code
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  
}

Widget Dashboard() {
  return SafeArea(
    child: Column(
      children: [
        Text("1")
        Text("2")
      ],
    ),
  );
}

please help me to solve this problem

Is the initState example you've shown above actually within a class definition, or is it a freestanding function?

https://dart.dev/tools/diagnostic-messages#super_in_invalid_context

this class is frestanding function

I solved the problem last night and made the class a statefull widget

In Flutter , if you want to initState, then put you override initState mehthod inside
    class _StatefulWidget extends State<StatefulWidget>{
}

For Example:
class _EvaluateQuizPageState extends State<EvaluateQuizPage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getTestAnswers();
  }

